# Showing hbase data in jaspersoft chart is creating "number of chart = number of rows"

Tags: jasper-reports, hbase

I am trying to fetch data from a Hbase table. Which has only two columns one is a country cod like "US" etc. and another is some analytic field that have an integer value it can be think as number of counts.

Now when i fetch these rows in Jaspersoft for creating chart, jaspersoft will create "number_of_chart = number_of_rows" and all the charts are similar. for example if i have 15 rows in my table it will create 15 similar chart in the report. Although bars created in chart are taking 15 different values of rows.

I am using below JSON query to fetch records from hbase.

```
{
  "tableName"         : "count_traf",
  "deserializerClass" : "com.jaspersoft.hbase.deserialize.impl.ShellDeserializer"
}
```

Also how i can create a parameter to fetch records that are inserted in last one hour in HBase table.

Comment: Move the chart out of the detail band in another band (title or summary).

Comment: Yes this works for me. When i take the chart in summary band it was shown only once. Thanks. 
But now i want to choose your solution as answer but its in comment section. How i can do it.

Comment: I moved it, thanks for your effort to accept answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Moved comment to answer:*

Your datasource contains 15 records, so the detail band will be iterated on 15 times. (once per record).

**The solution** is to move the chart in another band:

> `title` band - It will be displayed before detail band
>
> `summary` band - It will be displayed after detail band.

For your `HBase` query I suggest you post a new question with detail on your table, columns ecc